# Dynamically render GameObject in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, gameobject, culling

I am working on a AR project, where the virtual objects will be shown/hide in the scene based on information found in a text file. The text files will be updated from an external service. So I need to read the file on a frequent interval and update the scene. As a result I only have the Camera object and I am rendering the scene in `OnPreCull()` method.

The text files contain many objects but not all the objects are within the scene at any instance of time. I was looking for a way to render only those objects that are within the scene.

Will creating and placing the gameobjects in the `OnPreCull()` method crate any performance issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will creating and placing the gameobjects in the OnPreCull() method crate any performance issue?

Yes absolutely ... so would it if you do it in `Update` or any other repeatedly called method.

Instead you should rather Instantiate objects in `Awake` and only activate or deactivate them.

Let's say you have 3 objects `A`, `B` and `C` than I would make a kind of controller class that looks like

```
public class ObjectsController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Define in which intervals the file should be read/ the scene should be updated
    public float updateInterval;

    // Prefabs or simply objects that are already in the Scene
    public GameObject A;
    public GameObject B;
    public GameObject C;
    /* Etc ... */

    // Here you map the names from your textile to according object in the scene
    private Dictionary<string, GameObject> gameObjects = new Dictionary<string, gameObjects>();

    private void Awake ()
    {
        // if you use Prefabs than instantiate your objects here; otherwise you can skip this step
        var a = Instantiate(A);
        /* Etc... */

        // Fill the dictionary
        gameObjects.Add(nameOfAInFile, a);

        // OR if you use already instantiated references instead
        gameObjects.Add(nameOfAInFile, A);
    }
}

private void Start()
{
    // Start the file reader
    StartCoroutine (ReadFileRepeatedly());
}

// Read file in intervals
private IEnumerator ReadFileRepeatedly ()
{
    while(true)
    {
        //ToDo Here read the file

        //Maybe even asynchronous?
        // while(!xy.done) yield return null;

        // Now it depends how your textile works but you can run through 
        // the dictionary and decide for each object if you want to show or hide it
        foreach(var kvp in gameObjects)
        {
            bool active = someConditionDependingOnTheFile;

            kvp.value.SetActive(active);

            // And e.g. position it only if active
            if (active)
            {
                kvp.value.transform.position = positionFromFile;
            }
        }

        // Wait for updateInterval and repeat
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (updateInterval);
    }
}
```

---

If you have multiple instances of the same prefab you also should have a look at [Object Pooling](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling)

Comment: Thank you. This is really comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend adding each of the game objects to a registry and the switching them on or off (dis/enable SetActive) via the registry class's Update() cycle.

One Update() process to retrieve and handle the server file, another Update() process to dis/enable objects.  Might sound oversimplified however it's the fastest way I think of getting the result.

Good Luck!